# js getting remote div content into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a webpage where I put status of my webservice task. It looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="size">
        <c:out value="${size}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="isRunning">
        <c:out value="${isRunning}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="intIsRunning">
        <c:out value="${intIsRunning}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="status">
        <c:out value="${status}"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

after rendering I get this:

```
<body>
    <div id="size">
        100
    </div>
    <div id="isRunning">
        false
    </div>
    <div id="intIsRunning">
        0
    </div>
    <div id="status">
        0
    </div>
</body>
```

`size` is the size of a job and can be any int value. `isRunning` is `true` or `false` and `intIsRunning` is `1` or `0`. `status` is percentage completion of the job.

I'd like to be able to get content of those ids and put them into js variables on my other web page however I'm not js aficionado myself. 
For now I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.progress .bar').progressbar();
    var fetch = setInterval(loadStatus, 500);
    var isRunning;

    function loadStatus() {
        $.get('/status #intIsRunning', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("!");
            console.log("--->("+$(data).index("#status")+")");
        });

        isRunning = 0;
        console.log(">>" + isRunning);
        // console.log($('.progress .bar').prop(['data-transitiongoal']));
        // $('.progress .bar').prop(['data-transitiongoal']).load('/status #status');
        // $('.progress .bar [data-transitiongoal]').load('/status #status');
        // $('.bar').attr('data-transitiongoal', i.toString());
        // console.log("progress: "+progress);
        if (isRunning == 0) {
            clearInterval(fetch);
        }
    }
});
```

This script should query my status page for aforementioned values and put status into my progress bar as long as running is true. If running is false this script should stop but right now I can't extract those variables. Could anyone provide help? 
EDIT:
I got it to work that way:

```
<script type = text/javascript>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.progress .bar').progressbar();
                var fetch = setInterval(loadStatus, 500);
                var isRunning;
                var status;

                function loadStatus() {
                    $.get('/status', function (data) {
                        var remoteContent = $(data);
                        isRunning = parseInt($(remoteContent[11]).html());
                        status = parseInt($(remoteContent[13]).html());

                        if (isRunning == 0) {
                            status = 100;
                            clearInterval(fetch);
                            $("#progBar").hide();
                            $("#buttonDiv").hide();
                            $("#succesMessage").show();
                            //location.reload();
                        }

                        $('.progress .bar').attr("data-transitiongoal", status.toString()).progressbar();
                        console.log("isRunning: " + isRunning + " status: " + status + "%");
                    });
                }}
            );
        </script>
```

I'll check posted answer later this week.

Comment: Your loadStatus() function is never called. Your GET url seems invalid (space and hash??) To read the content of a div and fetch its text, you can use myText = $("div#status").text()

Comment: Why do you think it's never called? I get logs from within it. I thought that get(/url #divFromUrl) would get me the content of this div.

Comment: It gets called every 500 millis: `var fetch = setInterval(loadStatus, 500);`

Comment: @SokPomaranczowy, it's only the `load()` function that supports loading of page fragments by supplying a selector in the URL argument, `get()` has no such support.

Comment: Ooops yeah sorry, I missed that. My bad. @Sok : GET is used to make an ajax call (load an external resource in your page), not to select an element from the DOM. api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: @JeremyThille note that `.load()` does support loading of contents from a URL, filtering away anything that does not match the selector passed after the URL. But `.load()` is limited in other ways and not suitable in this case.

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg so what would be preferable way to load/get those properties? Commented lines doesn't work for me. `TypeError: $(...).prop(...) is undefined`

Comment: As I said, myText = $("div#status").text()  works fine to read the text of an element that is present in your DOM, and store it in the "myText" variable. Prop is for inner properties (checkbox that is checked/unchecked)

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, I still don't get one thing. How should I call this `myText = $("div#status").text() ` if I have remote webpage content loaded into `data` should it be `data.text()`?

Comment: If your data is HTML, you want to add it to the DOM using $("#someContainer").append(data). This will create your div#status and the others in your DOM. You can then use jQuery to target them : $("div#status").text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fetch = setInterval(loadStatus, 500);
  $('.progress .bar').progressbar();

  function loadStatus() {
    $.get('/status', function (data) {
      var $data = $(data), //turn ajax response (string) into JQuery collection
        isRunning = $data.find('#isRunning').text(),
        intIsRunning = $data.find('#isRunning').text(),
        size = $data.find('#isRunning').text(),
        status = $data.find('#isRunning').text();

      //Do something with the variables


      if (isRunning == 0) {
        clearInterval(fetch);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that the variables will all be strings. You can cast to a number using `status = parseInt(status, 10)` or to boolean using `isRunning = (isRunning != 'false')`, for example. Note though that with javascript's implicit type conversions this is often not necessary.